# Cookie not being affected by time

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using the script jquery cookie I need to set an expiration date of 3 years in future can someone explain how i thought i had set it with the following

This is the cdn of the jquery cookie plugin i am using

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

       // Delayed Modal Display + Cookie On Click
    $(document).ready(function () {


        console.log("Popup Code");
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            // we want to trap the user closing the popup and we also set the cookie expiery here to seven days.
            $.cookie('popupexpires', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
        })
        //if the cooke when the modal has been created is empty then display
        //the second one is for 
        if ($.cookie("popupexpires") == null) {

            console.log("Inside If Statment");

            // Show the modal, with delay func.
            $('#myModal').appendTo("body");                
            $("#myModal").appendTo("form:first");           
            function show_modal() {
                $.cookie('popupexpires', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
                $('#myModal').modal();
                console.log("Popup Displayed");
            }             
            // Set delay func. time in milliseconds
            window.setTimeout(show_modal, 10000);
        }




    });
</script>
```

I had asumsumed this meant 7 days 604800000 but when I check chrome its saying the following

Img of cookie showing expires after browsing session

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD5UK.jpg

**Edit 2**

Its still showing this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTOKb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had asumsumed this meant 7 days: 604800000

**Wrong!**

The `expires` property already is in days. [Reference: see 2nd example of "usage"](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

So change :

```
$.cookie('popupexpires', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
```

To:

```
$.cookie('popupexpires', 'true', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Please see my second screen shot its still showing that it will expire after session closes

Comment: That probably is due to an "out of realistic range" issue. Like @Adeno said, the amount of days you specified gives *«about 1 656 986 years»*.

Comment: «Specified days amount, out of range this is, for cookie... Even using the power of the Force. Shall Galactic Republic, notified they be.» - Yoda.

Comment: works fine now i had forget to change it one place thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery cookie plugin accepts a number of days until the cookie expires in the `expire` option.

604 800 000 days from now, is probably a bit too long *(about 1 656 986 years)*.

For three years, it would be something like (not counting leap years)

```
$.cookie('popupexpires', 'true', { expires: 365 * 3, path: '/' });
```

... or just 1095 days from now

Comment: In practice, I highly doubt that a cookie can last months or years... Since users often use cleaners like "CCleaner" or squarely change their devices... ;)

Comment: it what I have been instructed to do  its still not showing it if you check my second image plz

Comment: works fine now i had forget to change it one place thanks guys

Comment: Okay, cause testing it works fine as well -> https://jsfiddle.net/hwkjhfc9/